# Extracting or finding specific text in VBA from HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to **scrape** some data from the web for a report. The problem is that I can't find a way to iterate through the pagination on this specific page.

I was trying to find "Next" or directly the number of pages with `page.body.innerHTML` or `page.body.innerText`. Any idea on how to extract the total number of pages? Or how to check if the "Next" text is present in the HTML body?

Page code fragment:

```
    <div id="header_info_line">
    
<div id="pagination"><p>Pages:&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <strong>1</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="link_1">2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Link_2">3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Link_3">4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Link_4">5</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Link_5">6</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Link_6">7</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Link_7">8</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="Link_8">Next</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
(Total rows: 721.&nbsp;&nbsp;Total pages: 8.&nbsp;&nbsp;Rows per page: 100)</p></div>

    
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
```

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub rawData(tool As String, row As Long)

Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim page As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim dataE As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim dataEr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim dataEc As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim dataO As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim dataOr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim dataOc As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim pages As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim pagnr As Integer
Dim url As String
pagnr = 1
url = "Actual_Link"
 
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.send

page.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set dataE = page.getElementsByClassName("even")
Set dataO = page.getElementsByClassName("odd")
Set pages = page.getElementsByTagName("pagination")

'Debug.Print pages.innerHTML
        Call dataEven(dataE, dataEr, dataEc, row)
        Call dataOdd(dataO, dataOr, dataOc, row)
        pagnr = pagnr + 1
        If page.body.innerHTML = "Next" Then Debug.Print "found"
   

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: its an internal url so you wont be even able to acess it. i coudl provide more code if that helps